# Copy properties between objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some JSON loaded into JavaScript. The two objects have different formats. However, I want to copy the information from one to the other.

```
var myCollection = {
  name: '2007',
  items: [
    {
      name: 'item 1'
    }
  ]
};

var data = {
  path: 'somewhere',
  children: []
};
```

I want to copy all of the properties of the `data` object into the `myCollection.items[0]` object. In reality, `data` will have more properties. So, I'm trying to figure out how to do this as dynamically as possible instead of the brute force approach.

I was thinking to do

```
myCollection.items[0] = data;
```

In my head, this approach doesn't work though.

Comment: What you have are **JavaScript** object. They have nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a textual data format, that looks similar.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for correcting me. Always learning new things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push

```
myCollection.items.push(data);
```

or, if you can use ES6 and don't want to mutate structures, I think you could:

```
let newItems = [...myCollection.items, data]
let newObj = Object.assign({}, myCollection, {items: newItems})
```

Comment: But that's not what the op wants? This will add the data to he array, not merge it with the fist object I the array.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct. I'm trying to merge the data. Not just add items to the collection.

Comment: Could you say what exactly you want the final outcome to look like with your example